# About generating matrix of random numbers following Bernoulli distribution with a probability matrix in R

Tags: r

Assume a probability matrix is `A(nxm)`, then I want to generate a matrix(B) of random numbers of which each follows Bernoulli distribution with corresponding probability in `A`. That means `B[i,j] ~ Bernoulli(A[i,j)`. Is there anybody knowing how to do that conveniently in R? I even tried `rbinom(n*m,1,B)`, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
B <- matrix(rbinom(n*m, 1, A), n, m)
```

Or alternatively (close to the example you tried already in OP)

```
B <- A
B[] <- rbinom(n*m, 1, B)
```

Some example data (borrowed from @chinsoon)

```
set.seed(1000L)
n = 3
m = 3
A = matrix(runif(9), n, m)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you are looking for

```
apply(A, 1L:2L, function(p) rbinom(1, 1, p))
```

output:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    0    1    1
[2,]    1    0    1
[3,]    0    0    0
```

data:

```
set.seed(1000L)
A <- matrix(runif(9), 3, 3)
```